# Batch script issue (Tomcat install the service but start using batch file )

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window, command-prompt

I saved the below code as batch file but script able to install the tomcat service but not able to execute the line 4. Please let me know why it is not able to execute the line 4.

If i copied all the code and paste cmd window it is working fine and able to execute each command. but if double click on the batch file then not able execute the line 4 & 5. Please do the needful help. Thanks in advance

```
cd %CATALINA_HOME%
net stop SERVICE_NAME
sc delete SERVICE_NAME
service.bat install SERVICE_NAME
tomcat7.exe" //US//SERVICE_NAME --JvmMs=1024 --JvmMx=1024 --Jvm="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll" ++JvmOptions="-XX:MaxPermSize="512m" --Startup auto'
net start SERVICE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `call` command to start another batch script and [return to calling batch](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) as follows:

```
call service.bat install SERVICE_NAME
```

Recheck the `tomcat7.exe` line for proper use of `"` double quotes.

Use full paths to `service.bat` or `tomcat7.exe` if an error occurs similar to

> ```
>  'ddd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>  program or batch file.
> ```